# Unable to extract data from Observable Object

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to display data from an observed object.

Initially I tried to keep it simple, to merely display one member of a struct: 'base' (value: "stations").

```
struct Sample: Codable {
    let coord: Coord
    let weather: [Weather]
    let base: String
    let main: Main
    let visibility: Int
    let wind: Wind
    let clouds: Clouds
    let dt: Double
//    let sys: Sys
    let id: Int
    let name: String
//    let cod: Int
}
```

I did some defensive coding with '?' but I got the following compiler error:

[image]

So I replaced the '?' with '!', knowing that I should have some data.

[image]

I find this frustrating, coming from an imperative-paradigm background.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the data dump:

> Sample(coord: DataTaskPubTab.Coord(lon: -0.13, lat: 51.51), weather:
>   [DataTaskPubTab.Weather(id: 300, main: "Drizzle", description: "light
>   intensity drizzle")], base: "stations", main:
>   DataTaskPubTab.Main(temp: 280.32, pressure: 1012, humidity: 81,
>   tempMin: 279.15, tempMax: 281.15), visibility: 10000, wind:
>   DataTaskPubTab.Wind(speed: 4.1, deg: 80), clouds:
>   DataTaskPubTab.Clouds(all: 90), dt: 1485789600.0, id: 2643743, name:
>   "London")

Here's the Observable Object:

```
class StandardWeatherReportLoader: ObservableObject {
    @Published var networkMessage: String?
    @Published var hasAlert = false
    @Published var weatherReport: Sample?
    @Published var hasReport = false

    func doStandard() {
        let url = EndPoint.weather.path()
        var request = URLRequest(url: EndPoint.weather.path()!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data: Data?, _: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard error == nil else {
                    self.networkMessage = error?.localizedDescription
                    self.hasAlert = true
                    return
                }

                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                    let result = try decoder.decode(Sample.self, from: data!)
                    self.weatherReport = result
                    self.hasReport = true
                    print(result)
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this works:

```
struct StandardWeatherView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: Settings
    @ObservedObject var standardWeatherReportLoader = StandardWeatherReportLoader()

    init() {
        self.standardWeatherReportLoader.doStandard()
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color("FernGreen").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    if standardWeatherReportLoader.weatherReport?.base == nil {
                        Text("Sorry, NO data.")
                    } else {
                        Text(standardWeatherReportLoader.weatherReport!.base)
                    }

                    Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Weather Report"), displayMode: .inline)
            }.alert(isPresented: $standardWeatherReportLoader.hasAlert, content: { () -> Alert in
                Alert(title: Text(verbatim: standardWeatherReportLoader.networkMessage!))
            })
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very probably the web services data is not yet available when the view renders for the first time. So you shouldn't force unwrap the value with `!`. If you want to create a `Text()` element in both cases, you can simply use the `??` operation (see [Nil-Coalescing Operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID72) in the Swift language documentation):

```swift
Text(standardWeatherReportLoader.weatherReport?.base ?? "Sorry, NO data.")
```